# Need to execute sql injection attack on Modsecurity + crs v 3.3

Tags: security, owasp, mod-security

I am tasked to execute a successful attack (sqli, xss, csrf etc) on dvwa secured with modsecurity and crs v3.3 using encodings/ obfuscation
but i'm stuck!
any help or suggestion ?

Comment: Are you turning to Stack Overflow to find somebody to help you attack a site?

Comment: its for my thesis and am attacking dvwa